# Web socket error event

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm new in web socket protocol.If any error occurs in server side or client side I have to get it.But I have no idea about server side.
Now my code connect to websocket with `var connection = new WebSocket('ws://....);`.Also my connection have onClose onmessage and onopen functions. When any client send data my onmessage function gets the message and prints on console but when I unplug ethernet cable onerror function is not print anything.
How can I know any error occure in my side like this.

Comment: You can listen for event on your connection as `onerror` . Refer the following example  : https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

```Ex : 
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://....');
 connection.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
 connection.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
 connection.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
 connection.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) }; ```

Comment: you have to wait for the connection to drop after dis-connecting your ethernet cable; ~30s